# How to handle component link circular reference in DXA 2.0?

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-2.0

I have Book schema, that has a component link to similar books. One of the similar books, has a component link back to original component. In such way I got circular reference.

When publishing this component with DXA 2.0 TBBs expandLinkDepth parameter handles it nicely, and as result I got only couple of levels included in JSON.

However my main issue is on webapp side, it is failing during model mapping.

Book model has next property:

```
[SemanticProperty("s:similar_books")]
public List<Book> SimilarBooks { get; set; }
```

Default DataModelBuilder successfully maps couple of levels of Books to my property, however the last level that was restricted by TBB expandLinkDepth is failing with such message:

```
Unable to map field 'SimilarBooks' to property Book.SimilarBooks of type ...
```

It fails on this line of BuildEntityModel method of DefaultModelBuilder, because SchemaId is null.

```
SemanticSchema semanticSchema = SemanticMapping.GetSchema(entityModelData.SchemaId, localization);
```

Probably we can enhance DXA to avoid exception, however:

How should we handle such circular reference situations in general with DXA Models?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm. Sounds like an issue to be reported on [GitHub](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/issues)

Comment: Do you really want recursively  expanded Entity Models in the first place? You could also use a property of type `List<Link>` to get the similar books as links to other pages.

Comment: @RickPannekoek Yes, I need expanded EntityModel, but only for the first level. I don't need it recursively for all levels. Ok, will report it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this sounds like a defect in the DXA Framework in general, I think a work-around is possible, since you mentioned you don’t need more than one level expansion:

Create a new View Model Type, say `SimilarBook`, which maps to the same Schema/Properties as `Book`, but **don’t** let if have a `SimilarBooks` property.

Let the `Books.SimilarBooks` propery be of type `List<SimilarBook>`. This effectively breaks the recursive nature of the association.