# DXA Resolver Recursion Depth

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

We have set in the CMS, in Administration > DXA Resolver Recursion Depth

the following value

**DXA Resolver Recursion Depth=2**

but we are getting infinite loop when accessing the service model. Does this value have any effect? We have

COMPONENT A --> Keyword A --> meta Keyword B
COMPONENT B --> Keyword B --> meta Keyword A

So when the pageModel is being loaded, we've got an error:

java.lang.StackOverflowError

How we can solve this loop? I was considering to change the TBB and specify the depth to expand the components/kw links, but I wanted to explore if there's an alternative solution.

Comment: Please provide more info about the exception. Where does it occur? Model Service? Web App?  How does the Stack Trace look? Well, extremely long I assume given the Stack Overflow, but what is the context?

Answer (score 3):

The DXA Resolvers recursion depth is about the depth of Component Links that should be traversed when resolving the DCPs to publish.

Your exception does not occur during this resolving (I can tell from the fact it is a Java exception, whereas the resolving logic is implemented in .NET), but during (dynamic) expansion.

Your problem seems to be with recursive expansion of a cyclic link. It seems to be a similar problem as this: 
[How to handle component link circular reference in DXA 2.0?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18977/how-to-handle-component-link-circular-reference-in-dxa-2-0)

The suggested work-around is also applicable here.